# undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm newvbie in ruby on rails.. I'm having problem with gsub.. I everytime I go to the list of my store page it says "undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass"..

here is mycode :

```
def self.search(search_val, page = 1)
    @search_val = search_val.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
    search_query = "store_id LIKE '%#{ @search_val }%' OR english_name LIKE '%#{ @search_val }%' OR chinese_name LIKE '%#{ @search_val }%'"
select("jos_store.id, store_id, english_name, chinese_name, store_manager, delivery_area,year, week").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id as store_replenishment, store, MAX(stock_movement) AS stock_movement FROM jos_store_replenishment GROUP BY store) AS replenishment ON replenishment.store = jos_store.id").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_stock_movement ON jos_stock_movement.id = replenishment.stock_movement").where(search_query).order("year DESC, week DESC").paginate :page => page, :per_page => 15  
  end
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A good practice is doing `.to_s` when you are using string methods.

Comment: thanks guys but I already figure out the answer... i put a " unless search_val.blank? " before my gsub 
eg.

       unless search_val.blank?
       @search_val = search_val.gsub("'", "\\\\'")

Comment: Why the owner does not mark one of the Answers as actually accepted answer? At least, the explanations really worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `&` operator on `search_val`. It allows you to avoid null pointer exceptions without adding additional checks or using `to_s` to convert a string to a string.

So, you'll have something like this:

```
@search_val = search_val&.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
```

You can read more on the safe navigation operator here: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 3):

This means that `search_val` is in fact nil. You can easily verify this by printing out the value of `search_val`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your case, but the same `undefined` method `gsub` for `nil:NilClass` error happened with me after a few rollbacks and migrations.

Then, I restarted the server and works. Maybe this could be the case for some people that reached this topic searching on Google.